# Service not defined in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I am getting error of service not defined in angular js but I cant figure out why as my controller and module is perfectly connected:

application.js:

```
var myapp=angular.module('myApp', []);

myapp.service('productService', function() {
  var productList = "";

  var addProduct = function(newObj) {
     productList=newObj;
  };

  var getProducts = function(){
      return productList;
  };

  return {
    addProduct: addProduct,
    getProducts: getProducts
  };

});
```

controller1.js:

```
myapp.controller('contrl1', ['$scope','productService', function ($scope) {
    var st="datsat";

     productService.addProduct(st);
```

}]);

Controller 2:

```
myapp.controller('contrl2', ['$scope','productService', function ($scope) {

 $scope.products = productService.getProducts();
}]);
```

Also in the views I have given link to contoller.js file and application.js file

Comment: how do you suppose your controllers access the variable `productService` _if you don't put it in the parameter list_ ?

Comment: Yeah it solved but now the value of $scope.products in controller2 isnt changing to one mentioned in controller1,its staying default value as defined in application.js @Alnitak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right way to create your controller:

`myapp.controller('contrl2', ['$scope','productService', function ($scope, productService)`

When you're using DI and inline array annotation, the annotation array (strings) and function parameters should be synced (the same).

Comment: Yeah it solved but now the value of $scope.products in controller2 isnt changing to one mentioned in controller1,its staying default value as defined in application.js

Comment: You need to do the same in your first controller (specify service as parameter to your `function`).

Comment: Yeah already did for both controllers,when i visit first page and then goto second page value isnt changed

Comment: Are you using routes for browsing between pages?

Comment: No i am just changing value in the url bar

Comment: Well, you can mark this answer as accepted and ask another question about the right way to setup routes (and working with different pages).

Comment: ok cool just can you tell me if u know where I can learn about setting up routes